Retrieve HTTP requests statistics with Grafana / Prometheus / Tempo
I'm trying to monitor a java application deployed on several Kubernetes Deployments.
So far I've managed to ship

logs to Loki using Promtail
Kubernetes metrics to Prometheus using the operator
application JVM metrics through application instrumentation
traces data using the open-telemetry Java agent

What's missing is data about HTTP requests (request count per minute, number of 4xx/5xx errors, most time consuming requests by endpoint, ...) to show on Grafana dashboards.
I cannot touch the application code, and the instrumentation does not expose HTTP request metrics. So I don't have this data in Prometheus.
The most natural approach seemed like doing some aggregations on the traces stored on Tempo, but it's hard to understand what data is stored in traces, and it seems like I can't even sort requests by duration when querying Tempo data. In short Tempo doesn't seem to cooperate when aggregating its data to form a dashboard.
What's the right tool for the job? I'm open to changing my monitoring architecture, since I'd also like to correlate traces with logs (which I guess can only be done by injecting trace ids into logs), and that does not seem possible with my current setup.
I'm sorry if the question seems vague. I'm new to monitoring and just trying to figure it out.

So you cant touch the application code but are the dependent service Uris listed in an external config?
If this is the case you could setup something like nginx or envoy to act as an ingress/egress proxy and make this responsible for monitoring the http response codes, call durations etc.
